# How to efficiently calculate a^k mod m

Tags: number-theory

How can I efficiently calculate a<sup>k</sup> mod m where a,k,m are very large numbers and k might be up to 10<sup>9</sup> or more, a might be up to 10<sup>6</sup>.

Here a is a prime but k and m might not be primes.

Is my only option is calculating a<sup>1</sup> mod m, a<sup>2</sup> mod m, a<sup>4</sup> mod m etc based on binary representation of k or is there any easy way to reduce k to a smaller number?

Comment: There are many different algorithms and approaches for [modular exponentiaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). The WP article also links to some implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the "skip ahead" for linear congruential random number generators. There is formula for this in

*Brown, Forrest, B.: Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Strides. Argonne National Laboratory, 1994.* https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/pdf_files/anl-rn-arb-stride.pdf